# ASP.NET MVC How to display aggregation data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not too sure what the term is as I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC EF. I'm trying to display users that I have created with my create actionresult function onto my index view like Name, Work Address, Home Address, Asset Name,etc...

So far I can only get Name and Home Address to display properly by doing this:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      var clients = db.Clients.Include(c => c.HomeAddress);
      return View(clients.ToList());
 }
```

How would I display the other data as well like Asset Name, Work Address and so on?

My Client Model:

```
public class Client : Person {
    public ICollection<OccupancyHistoryRecord> OccupancyRecords { get; set;     }

        public ICollection<RentHistoryRecord> RentRecords { get; set; }

        public Asset Assets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Person Model:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Home Address")]
    public FullAddress HomeAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Work Address")]
    public FullAddress WorkAddress { get; set; }
}
```

FullAddress Model:

```
public Class FullAddress {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Suite")]
    public string UnitNum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Street Address")]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    public string Province { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Assets Model:

```
public Class Asset {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public FullAddress Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asking Rent")]
    public string AskingRent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OccupancyHistoryRecord> OccupancyRecords;

    public ICollection<RentHistoryRecord> RentRecords;

}
```

My Index View so far:

```
@model IEnumerable<RentalManagement.Models.Client>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Assets.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Assets.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HomeAddress) 
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WorkAddress)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomeAddress.StreetAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include all the virtual properties:

**EF Core version:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var clients = db.Clients
        .Include(p => p.Assets)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Address)
        .Include(p => p.Assets)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.OccupancyRecords)
        .Include(p => p.Assets)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.RentRecords)
        .Include(p => p.HomeAddress)
        .Include(p => p.WorkAddress)
        .ToList();
    return View(clients);
}
```

**EF 6 version:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var clients = db.Clients
        .Include(p => p.Assets.Select(s => s.Address))
        .Include(p => p.Assets.Select(s => s.OccupancyRecords))
        .Include(p => p.Assets.Select(s => p.RentRecords))
        .Include(p => p.HomeAddress)
        .Include(p => p.WorkAddress)
        .ToList();
    return View(clients);
}
```

Also mark this properties as virtual to enable lazy loading mechanism:

```
public virtual ICollection<OccupancyHistoryRecord> OccupancyRecords;
public virtual ICollection<RentHistoryRecord> RentRecords;
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a ThenInclude function for me?

Comment: `.ThenInclude` is a EF Core extension. I edited my answer and posted the EF 6 version also.